# How to have multiple sprite in one atlas for libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libGdx(Android) to create a simple animation

I used TexturePacker to create a sprite of multiple images ,I was using about 50 images , texture packer put them in more than one sprite sheet(  3 sprites) and exports a .atlas file with them , which contains all information about images:

```
TextureAtlas texture = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("image.atlas");
Animation anime = new Animation(1/30f, texture.getRegions());
```

and this is render method

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();


        batch.draw((TextureRegion)anime.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0,w,h);

    batch.end();

}
```

when I tested my code it works, but only the first sprite is appeared and loop, the other 2 sprites aren't !

Comment: The .atlas file contains information about all of the 3 sprites

Comment: texture.getRegions() give you a Array of all your 50 images(TextureRegions)

Comment: Log the timer: `Gdx.app.log("Elapsed", String.format("%.2f", elapsedTime));` to make sure that it is really counting up...